# Run NUnit Test After All Others Are Complete

Tags: nunit

I have a situation (detailed below) in which I want to run one NUnit test after all the other tests have completed.  I know that I can use the order attribute to *start* my tests in a certain order but in this case:

1. I want to attribute (or otherwise change) only one test out of several hundred.
2. I want this test to run *last*, not first.
3. I want this test to run after all other tests have *completed*, not after they've started.

I have experimented with OneTimeTearDown, but ideally this would run as a regular, named test and appear that way in the test results.

(Why)

I have several hundred named, hand-crafted tests that run against different folders of json test files.  Non-programmers add files to these folders from time to time.  The purpose of this final test is to introspect those folders and compare the contents on disk with the files for which a test has already been executed (these are recorded by each test).  If this indicates that there are untested files that, itself, constitutes a test failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question. Basically you want a meta-test... one that tests how well you are testing. For that reason, it's logical for it to actually **be** a test.

Unfortunately, NUnit only supports this sort of "run after everything" in a OneTimeTearDown. Now, you **can** Perform assertions in a OneTimeTearDown, but any failures are treated as errors, i.e. unexpected exceptions. For some purposes, this may be workable, but it doesn't look quite the same as a failure.

If I were doing this, I think I'd make it a separate analytical step in my script, after the tests had been run.